# Bluebird - Promise tracking progress

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I would like to track the progress of a promise call which I'll be making from `Node.js`, To be more clear, I need to show a progress bar with percentage util a success/error callback function is reached.

I've looked into the `Bluebird` docs, but found nothing related to this. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

My code is attached below,

```
const getAsync = Promise.promisify(cmd.get, { multiArgs: true, context: cmd })

=> // Need to show a progress bard over here 

getAsync('some command').then(data => { 
  spinner.color = 'green';
  spinner.text = 'Command completed..'
  spinner.succeed();
}).catch(err => {
  spinner.color = 'red';
  console.log('Error occured..', err)
})
```

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: There are only three stages of `promise`. `pending, resolved, rejected`. There is no intermediate stage between them.

Comment: How do you want to report the progress percentage? Can you update your code with that piece? Also have you checked http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/progression-migration.html and `Promise.coroutine`?

Comment: @Prakashsharma Thanks! It makes sense.

Comment: @HosseinPursultani Will check the link.. Thanks!

Comment: How does `cmd.get` report "progress" if you use it without promises?

Comment: @Bergi The `promisify` feature does that job for us.. Checkout here => http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html

Comment: @DavidR No it doesn't, but I think you misunderstood my question. What is `cmd.get` and how does it allow you to track progress? How would you have implemented the progress bar if you had not used promises anywhere?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, I'm yet to write the progress logic, Currently I don't have one in place.

Comment: @DavidR Well, in any case: what is impossible without promises is not made possible by promises.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do that, but not in the way you are asking. So you have 2 options:

1. Poll for the status in another call - the promise will have to modify some global var which the polling call can fetch.
2. Use sockets to communicate the progress to the client by emitting events.

The thing is, the promise is a promise, and it is either resolved or rejected, there is no progress status in it. And it might throw an error, but that's all.

Comment: Thanks for the response mate, Reg, point #1, is there any example available where we have a similar functionality?

Comment: For #1 I don't have a ready solution, it is just a concept. The idea is, on the client side, upon sending your request, to trigger a setInterval() function and call some URL periodically, say every 500 to 1000ms. When the status you are checking is done, clear the interval. Or use setTimeot() and upon receiving the status check it and call the same function again if necessary. On the server side make an endpoind to report the current status, and modify the current status in your async task. You may want to use some quick DB (Redis) to set an ID and progress for the given task.